Log to different databases per tenant using Serilog and ILogger
I need to change the connection string dynamically for Serilog.
In StartUp.cs, I have configured Serilog like:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var cm = new ConnectionManager(config);

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
            cm.GetConnectionString(cm.GetPropertyFromConfig("Serilog", "ConnectionName")),
            sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions { TableName = cm.GetPropertyFromConfig("Serilog", "TableName"), SchemaName = cm.GetPropertyFromConfig("Serilog", "SchemaName") })
        .CreateLogger();

    services.AddLogging(s =>
    {
        s.ClearProviders();
        s.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, dispose: true);
    });

    services.AddTransient(provider =>
    {
        var loggerFactory = provider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
        const string categoryName = "Any";
        
        return loggerFactory.CreateLogger(categoryName);
    });
}

In ChangeConnection.cs, I would like to be able to change the connection string
public ChangeConnection {

    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    
    public ChangeConnection(ILogger logger){
    
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public void SwapConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        // Change the connection string for logger so all subsequent calls write to new database
    }
}

Somewhere in code, make a call to change the connection string.:
_logger.LogInformation("Logging to Current Database");              
    
ChangeConnection.SwapConnection("new connection string");
    
_logger.LogInformation("Logging to New Database");


What is the actual problem? ILogger is only used to report log events, not write them to the targets. That's the job of the sink. You can have multiple sinks of the same type and use filters to restrict what gets written to each. Just as you can have two File sinks, one for Information and one for Warning and above, you can have different SQL Server sinks for different levels or categories

Why do you want to swap connections? That matters a lot. You need a different solution to split events by category, a different solution for multitenancy and a different solution if you want to switch to a different DB server to perform maintenance.

@PanagiotisKanavos -  I have a multi-tenant website.  From the website, I am able to change 'clients'.  When I am connected to ClientA, I want to log all events (i.e., error, debug, info, etc.) to ClientA's database.  When I switch to ClientB, I want to log all events to ClientB's database.  Each database has its own table to store the events.

After testing, I'm afraid this requirement cannot be realized.
I also find the closed github issue here: https://github.com/serilog-mssql/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/issues/246
If you still want the feature, you can raise a new github issue.

It can, by specifying multiple sinks targeting different databases with different filters based on category, level or other attributes. The question is incomplete and doesn't explain what the actual problem is

The solution I have to write to multiple sinks is below.
Configuration Serilog
Ensure that you have .Enrich.FromLogContext() set.
Next, I loop through a list of clients that I will be logging to. Each one has a different connectionstring.
        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                            .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
                            .Enrich.FromLogContext();

        // Create a Serilog filter for each of the Clients
        foreach (var client in clients)
        {
            string connectionString = string.Empty;

            switch (client)
            {
                case "Client1":
                    connectionString = client1ConnectString;
                    break;
                case "Client2":
                    connectionString = client2ConnectString;
                    break;
            }

            logger = logger.WriteTo.Logger(req => req
                                .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.WithProperty(client))
                                .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString,
                                    sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions { TableName = cm.GetPropertyFromConfig("Serilog", "TableName"), SchemaName = cm.GetPropertyFromConfig("Serilog", "SchemaName") },
                                    restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Verbose)
                                );
        }

        Log.Logger = logger.CreateLogger();

Create an extension class to assist with logging.  This allows me to use ILogger (versus Serilog.Log).
public static class LogExt
 {
     public static void LogWithContext(this ILogger logger, Action logAction, params KeyValuePair<string, object>[] contextDataParam)
     {
         Dictionary<string, object> contextData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
         foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in contextDataParam)
         {
             contextData.TryAdd(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
         }

         using (logger.BeginScope(contextData))
         {
             logAction.Invoke();
         };
     }
 }

Finally, I am able to log my calls using ILogger.
In code, I can call
_logger.LogWithContext(() => _logger.LogInformation("Log to client1 using ILogger"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Client1", ""));

_logger.LogWithContext(() => _logger.LogInformation("Log to client2 using ILogger"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Client2", ""));

To use the Serilog.Log static class, make the following call.
Serilog.Log.ForContext("Client1", "").Information("Log to Client1 using Serial.Log");
Serilog.Log.ForContext("Client2", "").Information("Log to Client2 using Serial.Log");

